How to get seamless display in javascript slideshow
I've written a basic slideshow with javascript. It downloads a randomly-chosen JPEG from a CGI script, scales it down if necessary, deletes the previously-displayed slide and displays the new one on the page, repeating this every two seconds.
The problem is that some of the JPEGs are very large (from 3MB to 20MB). The downloading (and, I presume, the scaling) take so long that sometimes, when the previous slide is deleted, several seconds elapse before the next one appears.
I'm sure this is because of the asynchronous nature of the processing, but I don't know how to control it. What I'd like is for each slide to appear for a minimum of two seconds or long enough that the next slide will appear without any delay.
(I'm using a placeholder image generator in this demo, so I don't know how well it will illustrate the delay problem.)


    function showSlides() {
        const my_img = document.createElement('img');
        fetch('https://picsum.photos/2000/600')
            .then(my_response => my_response.blob())
            .then(my_blob => {
                const my_url = URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);
                my_img.setAttribute('src', my_url);
                my_img.setAttribute('class', 'picture-div-img');
            })
            .catch(my_error => console.error('Error: ', my_error));

        /* NOTE: would like to wait until new slide is completely downloaded
           and rendered offscreen before deleting current slide and displaying
           new one */

        /* Delete current slide */
        const my_parent = document.querySelector('#slide-div');
        while (my_parent.firstChild) {
            my_parent.removeChild(my_parent.firstChild);
        }
        /* Insert new slide */
        my_parent.appendChild(my_img);
        setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); /* Change image every 2 seconds */
    }
    html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        /* prevent body from displacing */
        margin: 0;
        /* body should perfectly superimpose the html */
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .outer-div {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        height: 100%;
        /* Now create left/right margins */
        margin: 0 0.5em;
    }

    .inner-fixed-div {
        margin-top: 0.5em;
    }

    .inner-remaining-div {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        flex-grow: 1;
        /* hints the contents to not overflow */
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .picture-div {
        /* force the div to fill the available space */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .picture-div-img {
        /* force the image to stay true to its proportions */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /* and force it to behave like needed */
        object-fit: scale-down;
        object-position: center;
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body onload="showSlides();">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-fixed-div">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-remaining-div">
      <!-- This div will hold the <img> -->
      <div id="slide-div" class="picture-div">
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end of inner-remaining-div -->
  </div> <!-- end of outer-div -->
</body>
</html>




You can just preload the next image before displaying it. let img = document.createElement("IMG"); img.src = "someURL";

@ScottMarcus, I don't follow. Where would this go in my script?

This code could be placed anywhere that executes prior to needing the image to be displayed. By creating a new DOM object and setting its source, the image will be downloaded in the background and not be visible on the screen. When you are ready to display the image, you would append it to the DOM or change the src of your picture "frame" img to point to the src of the dynamically created image.

Perhaps what you really want is to wait 2 seconds after getting the image then  repeat.  Here we use a promise timer borrowed from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/125981 to do so;
No need to remove and insert, just update the source.


const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

async function showSlides(duration) {
  const my_parent = document.querySelector('#slide-div');
 // let mySource = "";
  const my_img = document.createElement('img');
  my_img.setAttribute('class', 'picture-div-img');
  my_parent.appendChild(my_img);
  fetch('https://picsum.photos/2000/600')
    .then(my_response => my_response.blob())
    .then(my_blob => {
     let mySource = URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);
      sleep(duration).then(() => {
        my_parent.querySelector('img').src = mySource;
        showSlides(duration);
      });
    })
    .catch(my_error => console.error('Error: ', my_error));
}
showSlides(2000);
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  /* prevent body from displacing */
  margin: 0;
  /* body should perfectly superimpose the html */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  /* Now create left/right margins */
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.inner-fixed-div {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.inner-remaining-div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* hints the contents to not overflow */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.picture-div {
  /* force the div to fill the available space */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.picture-div-img {
  /* force the image to stay true to its proportions */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* and force it to behave like needed */
  object-fit: scale-down;
  object-position: center;
}
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-fixed-div">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-remaining-div">
    <div id="slide-div" class="picture-div">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Could you include some explanation of what is going on synchronously and asynchronously in your fetch statement? I can figure out the sleep function, but I'd like to understand how this solution guarantees that, by the time the sleep finishes, there will be no unfinished business and mySource is fully ready to be displayed? What work is still being done as we enter sleep? Are we just assuming that two seconds should be enough to finish this? (hope that makes sense)

The two seconds is the time to wait AFTER the file is retrieved.  This is better since that remote resource may take an indeterminate time to read - say it is a large image and your internet is super slow and it takes 10 seconds to read; this uses the promise .then() to wait for your image the sleep is also a promise so that just waits however long you say. sleep(duration).then(() => { I reformatted to make that part more clear.

Keep in mind here also the fetch getting the resource THEN the static method is used ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static to get the source.

NOTE the fetch returns a promise so THEN it does the next thing .then(my_response => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Why let mySource=""? Does this release the URL from the temporally previous createObjectURL? Should I be calling revokeObjectURL() at some point?

That just sets up a scoped variable to use in the process.
Up to you regarding the revokeObjectURL - worth a read on the linked reference regarding that to help you decide.

NOTE you CAN remove that line and just update like this also for the variable let mySource = URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);  I updated to show that change

Thanks. I personally prefer not initializing mySource to "" since I tried to understand why that was necessary. I'll use your updated version.

Have you tried moving the insert new slide functionality inside the .then method? This would assure that it doesn't do anything before it have received the new image.


function showSlides() {
    const my_img = document.createElement('img');
    fetch('https://picsum.photos/2000/600')
        .then(my_response => my_response.blob())
        .then(my_blob => {
            const my_url = URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);
            my_img.setAttribute('src', my_url);
            my_img.setAttribute('class', 'picture-div-img');

            const my_parent = document.querySelector('#slide-div');
            while (my_parent.firstChild) {
                my_parent.removeChild(my_parent.firstChild);
            }
            /* Insert new slide */
            my_parent.appendChild(my_img);
            setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); /* Change image every 2 seconds */
        })
        .catch(my_error => console.error('Error: ', my_error));
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    /* prevent body from displacing */
    margin: 0;
    /* body should perfectly superimpose the html */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.outer-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    /* Now create left/right margins */
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.inner-fixed-div {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.inner-remaining-div {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    flex-grow: 1;
    /* hints the contents to not overflow */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.picture-div {
    /* force the div to fill the available space */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.picture-div-img {
    /* force the image to stay true to its proportions */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* and force it to behave like needed */
    object-fit: scale-down;
    object-position: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body onload="showSlides();">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-fixed-div">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-remaining-div">
      <div id="slide-div" class="picture-div">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




It's a vast improvement, but I still notice a short (~1 second) blank before displaying a very large image. The blank-out begins when the removeChild() executes, so I assume it's the appendChild(my_img) that's taking an appreciable amount of time. Does that sound right? Is there a way to force that processing to complete before hitting the removeChild?

@Chap hmm. the first thing that comes to mind is a dirty solution with a setTimeout for some seconds and "hope" it's loaded. but you didn't hear it from me! ;) I was hoping my solution did that, wait until processing is complete. But maybe it's just a thing for so large images
